# GraphQL: Filtering, sorting and paging on nested entities from separate data sources?

Tags: microservices, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm attempting to use graphql to tie together a number of rest endpoints, and I'm stuck on how to filter, sort and page the resulting data.  Specifically, I need to filter and/or sort by nested values.

I cannot do the filtering on the rest endpoints in all cases because they are separate microservices with separate databases.  (i.e. I could filter on `title` in the rest endpoint for articles, but not on author.name). Likewise with sorting.  And without filtering and sorting, pagination cannot be done on the rest endpoints either.

To illustrate the problem, and as an attempt at a solution, I've come up with the following using `formatResponse` in [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-server), but am wondering if there is a better way.

I've boiled down the solution to the most minimal set of files that i could think of:

data.js represents what would be returned by 2 fictional rest endpoints:

```
export const Authors = [{ id: 1, name: 'Sam' }, { id: 2, name: 'Pat' }];

export const Articles = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Aardvarks', author: 1 },
  { id: 2, title: 'Emus', author: 2 },
  { id: 3, title: 'Tapir', author: 1 },
]
```

the schema is defined as:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
} from 'graphql';

import {
  Articles,
  Authors,
} from './data';

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Author',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    }
  }
});

const ArticleType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Article',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    author: {
      type: AuthorType,
      resolve(article) {
        return _.find(Authors, { id: article.author })
      },
    }
  }
});

const RootType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Root',
  fields: {
    articles: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ArticleType),
      resolve() {
        return Articles;
      },
    }
  }
});

export default new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootType,
});
```

And the main index.js is:

```
import express from 'express';
import { apolloExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server';
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import _ from 'lodash';
import rql from 'rql/query';
import rqlJS from 'rql/js-array';

import schema from './schema';
const PORT = 8888;

var app = express();

function formatResponse(response, { variables }) {
  let data = response.data.articles;

  // Filter
  if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(variables, 'q')) {
    // As an example, use a resource query lib like https://github.com/persvr/rql to do easy filtering
    // in production this would have to be tightened up alot
    data = rqlJS.query(rql.Query(variables.q), {}, data);
  }

  // Sort
  if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(variables, 'sort')) {
    const sortKey = _.trimStart(variables.sort, '-');
    data = _.sortBy(data, (element) => _.at(element, sortKey));
    if (variables.sort.charAt(0) === '-') _.reverse(data);
  }

  // Pagination
  if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(variables, 'offset') && variables.offset > 0) {
    data = _.slice(data, variables.offset);
  }
  if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(variables, 'limit') && variables.limit > 0) {
    data = _.slice(data, 0, variables.limit);
  }

  return _.assign({}, response, { data: { articles: data }});
}

app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), apolloExpress((req) => {
  return {
    schema,
    formatResponse,
  };
}));

app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
}));

app.listen(
  PORT,
  () => console.log(`GraphQL Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

For ease of reference, these files are available at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/scags9876/d96da7c2dbc98c43f8d735447928480a).

With this setup, I can send this query:

```
{
  articles {
    id
    title
    author {
      id
      name
    }
  } 
}
```

Along with these variables (It seems like this is not the intended use for the variables, but it was the only way I could get the post processing parameters into the formatResponse function.):

```
{ "q": "author/name=Sam", "sort": "-id", "offset": 1, "limit": 1 }
```

and get this response, filtered to where Sam is the author, sorted by id descending, and getting getting the second page where the page size is 1.

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Aardvarks",
        "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Sam"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or these variables:

```
{ "sort": "-author.name", "offset": 1 }
```

For this response, sorted by author name descending and getting all articles except the first.

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Aardvarks",
        "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Sam"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Emus",
        "author": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Pat"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I am using the formatResponse function for post processing to do the filtering/paging/sorting.   .

So, my questions are:

1. Is this a valid use case?
2. Is there a more canonical way to do filtering on deeply nested properties, along with sorting and paging?

Comment: I know you're not using relay, but have you read about relay [connections](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm)? I believe that it will help you understanding how to ask for paginated collections.

Now, regarding on how to filter and paginate in your architecture (I myself have a similar one at hands), I believe that your only solution is to somewhere intersect your data. Picking on your example, if you want to filter by `author.name`, you will have to first search for authors with that name, and **then** search for articles with those authors.

Comment: Not using `GraphQL` yet, but doing some research on the subject with pagination in mind and I came accross this article [Understanding Pagination REST GraphQL and Relay](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/understanding-pagination-rest-graphql-and-relay-b10f835549e7#.o70ujlmt0) which talks about upcoming pagination feature. This might be helpful to answer your questions around it.

Comment: The problem with starting with author.name is that you assume the author type will be resolved from a single source which can be efficiently sorted. But in a sharded environment we might have two or more underlying sources of data requiring two isolated queries, both ending up with Author results. As far as I can see, the only generic way to do the kind of complex sort discussed here is with a filter process which is explicitly designed to sort graphql results.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this a valid use case? Is there a more canonical way to do filtering on deeply nested properties, along with sorting and paging?

Major part of original questing lies on segregating collections on different databases on separate microservices. In fact, it's nessasary to perform collection joining and subsequent filtering on some key, but it's directly impossible since there is no field in original collection to filter, sort or paginate.

Strightforward solution is perform full or filtered queries to original collections, and then perform joining and filtering result dataset on application server, e.g. by lodash, such at your solution. In is possible for small collections, but in general case causes large data transfer and unefficent sorting since there is no index structure - real RB-tree or SkipList, so with quadratic complexity it's not very good.

Dependent on resource volume on application server, special cache and index tables can be build there. If collection structure is fixed, some relations between collection entries and their fields can be reflected in special search table and update respectively on demain. It's like find & search index creation, but not it database, but on application server. Of cource, it will consume resources, but will be more fast than direct lodash-like sorting.

Also task can be solved from another side, if there is access to structure of original databases. Key is denormalization. In counter for classical relation approach, collections can have dublicate information for avioding further join operation. E.g., Articles collection can have some information from Authors collection, which is nessasary to perform filtering, sorting and pagination in further operations.